# literally vs literarily

Tags: word-usage

Dictionaries say both 'literally' and 'literarily' could be adverb, but they say nothing about the usage of literarily.

So, what would be the differences in usage for these two words?

Comment: What "dictionaries" say this? It's wrong: *literarily* is the adverb form of *literary*.

Comment: @StoneyB, oops, I will update my question. Basically, I just want to ask the differences between these two words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though they may seem similar, they are actually not that related to each other.

*literally* means that something means exactly what it says:

> in the literal or strict sense: She failed to grasp the metaphor and interpreted the poem literally.
>   [source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/literally)

*literarily* means something in relation to books or literature:

> In a literary manner.
>   [source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/literarily)

See also the [Oxford definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literarily).

It may be worth noting that *literally* is much more used than *literarily* and will therefore be more important to learn for those who are learning English.

Comment: It's worth noting that [*literally* is hundreds of times more common than *literarily*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=literally+%2F+literarily&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28literally%20/%20literarily%29%3B%2Cc0), so while learners will definitely need to know *literally*, they might not really need *literarily*.

Comment: @Maxion, Do you really use literarily in practice? It seems to me that most of time we just use literally. What's the difference indeed between literally and literarily?

Comment: @dan,  as they answer says,  these two words don't have any special relationship. An example of literarily: "Proust is known for writing literarily."

Comment: @dan, it can mean "in a literary manner" as in this answer, or "in a way related to literary matters", as in the examples at oxford dictionaries linked by Maxion in comments. It never means the same thing as *literally*.

Answer (score 1):

"Literarily" goes deeper than "literally" because, the former is associated with deeper information gained from books or literature while the latter is simply a metaphor meaning the exact or face-value interpretation of something being said.